# wordpress How create select dependent dropdown by meta values or categories

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, drop-down-menu

We had 3 custom fields

- Brand
- Model
- Features (multi input in an array )

  need dependent drop down form when
- select Brand (or Category) > show drop down menu contain all Models (related to this selection)
- select Model > show all features of this model from meta value

You can see example here http://bit.ly/1Q2z9tE

We tried with these codes but not worked

```
    $rd_args = (array(
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',

        'order' => 'ASC',
             'meta_query' => array(
            array(
            'key' => 'brand',
            ),
            array(
            'key' => 'model',
            )
        )
    ));
     
    $rd_query = new WP_Query( $rd_args );

        $the_query = new WP_Query(array( 'meta_key' => 'votes_count', 'meta_value' => '1' ));

    $html_out = '';
    $html_out = '<select id="office-chooser2" >';
    $html_out .= '<option value="none">Select an Office</option>';
    $select  = '<select id="office-chooser">';
    $select .= '<option value="none">Select an Office</option>';


    while ($rd_query->have_posts()) : $rd_query->the_post();

        // add each div with excerp. It's ID is unique and correlates to value of select drop down
            $brand = (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'brand', true));
            $model = (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'model', true));
        $html_out .= '<option value="office-'.$post->ID.'" class="office-entry" id="office-'.$post->ID.'">'.$model.'</option>';
        $select   .= '<option value="office-'.$post->ID.'">'.$brand.'</option>';
    endwhile;

    // wrap up $select
    $select .= '</select>';
    $html_out .= '</select>';

    echo $select;
    echo $html_out;


    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($){
            $('#office-chooser').change(function(){
                var $selected_office = $(this).val();
                if(($selected_office == 'none') ){
                    $('div.office-entry').hide();
                    $('#office-chooser2').hide();
                    $('#' + $selected_office).hide();
                } else  { 
                $('#' + $selected_office).show();
                                $('#office-chooser2').show();

    }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: *"codes but not worked"* is not a proper problem description that anyone can use to troubleshoot from. Please provide proper details

Comment: @charlietfl We have meant "not worked as we want" because first select drop down contain repeated meta key with same value !!!

  ,but we need first select brand then it show model related to then it will display features of this model from its meta values